# Recursive function printing all values twice

Tags: python

When I run my code the output is correct, it's just printing out two of each value.

Can somebody enlighten me on what is going wrong?

```
number = int(input("Enter any number: "))
tfcheck = True

def reducer(number):
    if (number % 2) == 0:     
        number = int(number/2)
    else:
        number = number * 3 + 1
  
    print(number)
    return number
    

while tfcheck:
    if reducer(number) == 1:
        tfcheck = False
        break
    else:
        number = reducer(number)
   
reducer(number)
```

This code should divide a user inputted number down to 1 and display each step, this is a sample output of what I'm getting if I put in 3:

```
10
10
5
5
16
16
8
8
4
4
2
2
1
1
```

Cant see where I'm going wrong with it

Comment: Count how many times you call `reducer` when its result isn't 1.

Comment: out of that no need to do `tfcheck = False`and `break`

Comment: Remove the print from inside your function and print the reducer outside whenever you want it

Comment: While number != 1:
    Number = reducer(number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reducer` prints the number. In your while loop, you call reducer twice:

```py
while tfcheck:
    if reducer(number) == 1:  # Call once
        tfcheck = False
        break
    else:
        number = reducer(number)  # Call again
```

Thus, the number will get printed twice. To fix this, you can just call reducer once and store its result in a temporary variable.

```py
while tfcheck:
    reduced = reducer(number)  # Call once
    if reduced == 1:
        tfcheck = False
        # break  # No need to break since you set tfcheck = False
    else:
        number = reduced  # Do not call again
```

Answer (score 0):

**Iterative Approach:**
Solution provided in the question prints the number inside the function and since in the while loop reducer is called twice with same value as it executes else statement unless the return value is 1.

Therefore solution to this problem would be simply printing the number in else statement of while loop.

```
number = int(input("Enter any number: "))
tfcheck = True

def reducer(number):
    if (number % 2) == 0:     
        number = int(number/2)
    else:
        number = number * 3 + 1
  
    return number
    

while tfcheck:
    if reducer(number) == 1:
        tfcheck = False
        break
    else:
        number = reducer(number)
        print(number)
   
print(reducer(number))
```

**Recursive Approach:**

A better approach would be using this method as it eliminates repetitive function call, while loop along with if-else statements can be eliminated. Also you will be able to understand the code better.

Yes it is true Python has recursion limit, if the use case is exceeding the limit then go for Iterative method. But for most cases the limit will not be crossed.

```
def reducer(number):

    if number==1:
        return 1
    if (number % 2) == 0:     
        number = int(number/2)
    else:
        number = number * 3 + 1
    print(number)
    reducer(number)

reducer(int(input("Enter any number: ")))
```

Comment: How is this better? Please [edit] to clarify. I wouldn't use a recursive approach for this because Python has a recursion limit, and it can be easily done with an iterative approach.